# Camellia cipher - is it a symmetric or asymmetric cipher?

Tags: public-key, symmetric, modes-of-operation, encryption, camellia

I read a wiki page about [Camellia cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camellia_%28cipher%29) and know that it is a block cipher that can use 128-bit, 192-bit or 256-bit keys. But I cant find any information about if its a symmetric cipher (uses one key for both encryption and decryption) or asymmetric cipher (uses different key for encryption and different key for decryption)?

And in which cipher modes can Camellia operate? (ECB,CBC, ...)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Camellia is a symmetric block cipher; the same key is used for both encryption and decryption.  And, as a block cipher, it can be used in any of the standard modes (CBC, CTR, CFB, GCM, even ECB, although use of ECB for any block cipher is not encouraged).

Comment: Just another question: should be a key for Camellia a random-generated key, right?

Comment: It has the same requirement as just about any other block cipher; the key must not be guessable by an adversary; ideally, this is with a random key; that is, either a key generated randomly, or from a good Key Derivation Function (based on inputs that are unguessable)